# Auto fill column when inserting data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a question and hope you can help me. How can I auto-fill a column and make sure it has the same value every time I insert the same value in another column? Here is the example:

```
CREATE TABLE courses(
    course_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    course_name varchar(50) NOT NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE test(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
course_id INT NOT NULL,
course_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
person_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(course_id) REFERENCES courses(course_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Imagine I have the 'courses' table with some values, like:

```
INSERT INTO courses(course_name) VALUES ('Science Computer'),('Engineering'),('English')
```

What can I do to guarantee that whenever I insert into 'test' a course_id value of '1' it will fill the course_name column with 'Science Computer' and if course_id = 2, course_name will be 'Engineering'? I'm using POSTGRESQL, thanks everyone.

Comment: Normalize the database, just insert the course id and join on the courses table if you need the name.

Comment: This is the classic example to use Boyce-Codd's Third Normal Form and even Codd's (architect of the relational model) work on avoiding the redundancy of data. All *course* information is entered once in its relation and should not be repeated in related entities. Keys relate the two tables as you already have set up.